# How do i maximize $\max_{\gamma}\sum_{|\alpha|=q}\binom{\alpha}{\gamma}$?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, co.combinatorics

I'm trying to find the following maximum: $\max_{\gamma}\sum_{|\alpha|=q}\binom{\alpha}{\gamma}$. Here $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n),\gamma=(\gamma_1,\ldots, \gamma_n)$ are multi-indices. The binomial coefficient is defined as $\binom{\alpha}{\gamma}=\frac{\alpha !}{\gamma! (\alpha-\gamma)!}=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\alpha_i !}{\gamma_i! (\alpha_i-\gamma_i)!}=\prod_{i=1}^n\binom{\alpha_i}{\gamma_i}$. We take the usual convention that $\binom{n}{r}=0$ if $r$ goes out of range, i.e. $r<0$ or $r>n$.

This maximum is well-defined and fully determined in terms of $n$ and $q$. Could anyone help?

Here is the solution for $n=1$. The sum $\sum_{|\alpha|=q}\binom{\alpha}{\gamma}$ is the single term $\binom{q}{\gamma}$, so the monotonicity of the binomial distribution gives the maximum at $\binom{q}{\lfloor q/2\rfloor}$.

For $n=2$, the problem amounts to maximizing $\max_{r,s}\sum_{i=0}^q \binom{i}{r}\binom{q-i}{s}=\max_{r,s}\sum_{i=r}^{q-s} \binom{i}{r}\binom{q-i}{s}$.

For general $n$, here is my very rough estimate. The basic inequality $\binom{\alpha}{\gamma}\le \binom{|\alpha|}{|\gamma|}$ implies $\max_\gamma \sum_{|\alpha|=q}\binom{\alpha}{\gamma}\le \max_{\gamma}\sum_{|\alpha|=q}\binom{q}{|\gamma|}\le \binom{n+q-1}{n}\binom{q}{\lfloor q/2\rfloor}$. The coefficient $\binom{n+q-1}{n}$ that pops out is the number of multi-indices $\alpha$ of length $q$.

More rewrites and updates to come. Thanks to Gerhard in advance!

Comment:  "I don't some work" is a misprint, right? Did you mean "I've done some work"?


Comment: Could you give the definition of the multi-indexed binomial coef? 

Comment: Have you tried replacing the coefficients with a bunch of gamma functions and the sum with an integral?

Comment: Is there reason to suspect \alpha=q does not work? If so, what is that reason? Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.03.12

Comment: Oh, I get it now.  For each gamma, you are interested in the sum, and you want to know which gamma produces the largest sum, I'm guessing for all gamma with weight n? Gerhard "Time to Clean My Glasses" Paseman, 2011.03.12

Comment: @Steve, I will try as you said.

Comment: This problem seems interesting; it also seems under-specified.  If you had a couple of examples that you computed for small n and q, or a conjecture, I might help.  For now, I am uncertain how to interpret alpha - gamma in the case one of the components is zero or negative.  If you do more work in specifying the question, I will think about it some more.  My gut feeling is that gamma has all coefficients nearly equal, or all but one coefficients equal to 1 or 0, depending on how you limit gamma.  I look forward to the rewrite. Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.03.12

Comment: You're welcome.  If Gjergji's answer below doesn't satisfy you, I will think about it some more.  I'm glad you took the time to rewrite it; it's much more clear to me now, and looks like a good MathOverflow question.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.03.12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I claim that $$\sum_{|\alpha|=q} \binom{\alpha}{\gamma}=\binom{n+q-1}{|\gamma|+n-1}$$ 
and so the answer is simply all $\gamma$ with $|\gamma|=\lfloor\frac{n+q-1}{2}\rfloor -n+1$. A quick proof comes from the following generating function
$$\frac{x^l}{(1-x)^{l+1}}=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \binom{p}{l}x^p$$ and looking at the coefficient of $x^{n+q-1}$ in the identity
$$x^{n-1}\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{x^{\gamma_i}}{(1-x)^{1+\gamma_i}}=\frac{x^{|\gamma|+n-1}}{(1-x)^{n+|\gamma|}}$$